# Why am I getting many lists after appending, I only want one

Tags: python, list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhl0N.png)
I have tried many different things, and yes my python skill is limited, but why do I get 10 lists instead of one with my code. How to change my loop to only append to one list not 10? I get 10 results from my query, and I want to just add those ten items to a single list.

```py
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

list = []
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_words = "test"
date_since = "2020-06-24"
date_to = "2020-06-26"

# Collect tweets
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
q=search_words,
lang="en",
since=date_since,
until=date_to).items(10)

# Iterate and print tweets
for tweet in tweets:
    list.append(tweet.user.screen_name)
    print(list)
```

Comment: Fix the indentation first, please

Comment: What makes you think you have 10 lists?

Comment: Show us the output that makes you think there are 10 lists.

Comment: Also never call your list `list` as it will overwrite the builtin version

Comment: Why are you printing `list` from within the loop?

Comment: I just changed indents, and uploaded an image of my results

Comment: `print(list)` is inside the loop, so it is printing 10 times.

Comment: You have one list that you print ten times. Voting to close because claimed problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    list.append(tweet.user.screen_name)
```

To:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    list.extend(tweet.user.screen_name)

print(list)
```